# Get last 12 months of data grouped by month even if 0

Tags: php, mysqli, group-by, left-join

I am trying to get a COUNT of the last 12 months of appointments grouped by month for output into a chart.  The following works fine but I need it to return 0 if no results for each month.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id) as total_month FROM appointments WHERE created >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 365 DAY GROUP BY Month(created)";
    $query = $mysqli->real_escape_string($query);
      if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
        while($row = $result->fetch_array())
          {
          $month_total_appointments .= $row['total_month'].',';
        }
      } 

echo $month_total_appointments;


================================================================
    Simple table structure and example for appointments Table
    id    customer_name    created

    1     John             2020-05-01 08:00:00 <= stored as datetime
    2     Mike             2020-04-01 09:00:00
    3     Steve            2020-02-01 10:00:00

    Output would be 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1 
======================================================
```

Current output is: 1,1,1

I've read some use a month table and LEFT JOIN but everything i've tried doesn't seem to work.  Can anyone help please?

Comment: Calling `real_escape_string` on a query makes absolutely no sense. Why are you doing this? That will only damage data. Don't do that. It won't save you if `$prefix` has SQL-injection stuff in it.

Comment: Seeing things like `$prefix."appointments"` is usually a sign you need to make your database properly relational. It should not be necessary to have *N* tables with the same structure.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, doesn't really help answer my question though.  Prefix didn't really have anything to do with tables having the same structure but I removed it to avoid any confusion on the question.

Comment: You're talking about data we can't see. Might be worth experimenting on something like [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to make a usable example.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get zeroes for rows that aren't there. Grouping combines rows that match particular criteria, but it can't fabricate them out of nothing.

That's why it's typical to include the grouping criteria in the results:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), MONTH(created) AS created_month
  FROM appointments
  WHERE created >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 365 DAY
  GROUP BY created_month
```

Then you can expand that in your application code to fill in the missing values. The alternative is you need a fully populated list of all possible dates to `JOIN` against.

Keep in mind the `MONTH()` thing will wrap around and group January 2020 with January 2021. You may want to split this up:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), YEAR(created) AS created_year, MONTH(created) AS created_month
  FROM appointments
  WHERE created >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 365 DAY
  GROUP BY created_year, created_month
```